# Discover contact number type

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I'm using this code to know a contact name, his phone number and his ID

```
String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
```

I need to disover what's the number type(work, home, mobile). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Phone.TYPE

```
 int phoneType = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
```

Comment: I think it's right. I don't know because I have 7 people, but it only update the number of 3. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: 3 is TYPE_WORK http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#TYPE_WORK

Comment: No, i said, i have 7 people, but when I ask program to update them all, it only update 3 of them.

Comment: Post another question about this and post your code in the question.